# Kerberos LDAP and Ubuntu Login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login, ldap, kerberos

I setup Kerberos and LDAP for directory management at an institution for Ubuntu OS.  I got LDAP configured correctly and Kerberos.  The user's home directory is in an LDAP directory.  When the user logs in, the process of authentication grants the user access to the computer.  But they don't get write permission to the LDAP partition, which leads to the Desktop Environment (DE) being useless.  From the command line, typing klog and providing the password fixes the problem, but from the DE, there is never a change to open a terminal to type klog.  Of course, the expected behavior is for klog to be called during login so the user gets straight access to their LDAP directory.

Am I missing a package ? or should I just add klog somewhere in the login process ? (if so, where ? )

Answer (score 2):

Do you have [pam-krb5](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/pam-krb5/) set up to allow logins? If so, once a user is authenticated, they should have a Kerberos TGT; if you set up the LDAP server properly, that TGT should be enough for them to perform an authenticated bind.

If it's not the case that the users are getting TGTs automatically when they login, investigate pam-krb5 to get that part working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using the configuration documentation from a CentOS document where 
the file /etc/libnss-ldap.conf in CentOS is named /etc/ldap.conf in Ubuntu.